# Is there a way to get a CSV of full network status? smthng like all-descriptors.new?

Tags: network-health

I'm looking for options for `torrc` or another ways to force my tor daemon to fetch full network status.

E.g. today, my `/var/lib/tor/cached-descriptors.new` contain only records about 1032 relays, however http://torstatus.blutmagie.de show me more than 5000 relays.

I'm already enable in the `/etc/tor/torrc`:

```
DownloadExtraInfo 1 
FetchUselessDescriptors 1
```

Am I must increase `ulimit` for Tor from 4096 to 10000 file descriptors:

```
$ ulimit -H -n 
4096
```

And this option of torrc:

```
ConnLimit 10000
```

---

I've found `PathsNeededToBuildCircuits` option in https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en

> PathsNeededToBuildCircuits NUM
>
> Tor clients don’t build circuits for user traffic until they know
>   about enough of the network so that they could potentially construct
>   enough of the possible paths through the network. If this option is
>   set to a fraction between 0.25 and 0.95, Tor won’t build circuits
>   until it has enough descriptors or microdescriptors to construct that
>   fraction of possible paths. Note that setting this option too low can
>   make your Tor client less anonymous, and setting it too high can
>   prevent your Tor client from bootstrapping. If this option is
>   negative, Tor will use a default value chosen by the directory
>   authorities. (Default: -1.)

I'm trying to add to my `torrc`:

```
PathsNeededToBuildCircuits 0.9
```

However, my Tor v0.2.3.25 (git-3fed5eb096d2d187) running on Linux, wantn't to launch, with next `warn`:

> [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Unknown option
>   'PathsNeededToBuildCircuits'. Failing.

---

Related my old quetsion: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1632/http-torstatus-blutmagie-de-csv-list-of-current-result-set

Answer (score 1):

The [network page](https://metrics.torproject.org/network.html) of the [Tor metrics portal](https://metrics.torproject.org/) lists approximately 5300 relays. This number should also be known to your Tor client as every client needs a full network view. So you don't need to change your configuration.

The information about all relays is in `cached-microdesc-consensus`. The entries look like:

```
r einfo AOsaxadU+MSjQjiVx4CM7JzZ3TQ 2014-03-03 23:35:37 46.163.118.42 9001 0
m zQPi5J/Qoj/ZxtirMDHnulkVT/f7C9kYvzJ4tSQQZ24
s Exit Fast Guard Named Running Stable Valid
```

When I count all entries the file on my machine lists 5269 relays.

Comment: 5344 on my side, however option `PathsNeededToBuildCircuits` tell about that client or relay may not have a full network information. I'm looking for the way to force fetching the full information about network.